# How do i get each word to start with a capital letter in a span tag

Tags: html, css

My HTML is as follows

```
<h1><span>Check</span> <span>this</span> <span> out</span></h1>
```

and my css is as follows

```
h1{
text-transform: capitalize;

}

h1 span{
text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Funny thing only the word 'Check' starts with the capital letters .How do i get the span tags to capitalize also

Comment: This works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kQCjz/

Comment: yeah, me too http://jsfiddle.net/d5R8H/

Comment: seems to be a problem in FF only

Comment: Oh ! Sorry made a mistake there are 3 span tags

Comment: There seemed to have been a bug in a very early Beta Firefox release like 9 years ago (http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&p=5679715). Tell me your Firefox is up-to-date.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 14.0.1, still works.

Comment: Im  on the latest 14.0.1

Comment: Appears to be a non-reproducible problem, possibly caused by other CSS code that hasn’t been disclosed.

Answer (score 3):

My code is

```
          {text-transform: uppercase}
```

Use this code for start a letter as a capital.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine you must have some sort of overiding css see the fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/3MhpQ/

Really old firefox had issues with this if you on any thing older that 9 please just upgrade, as the user stats for any one lower is very small

Comment: Ive double checked there is no overriding  CSS .However if i mark the span tags as inline-block it works

Comment: What version off firefox are you using >?

Comment: well as we show from the jsfiddle it seems to be working fine so there has to be something overiding, if you modify the jsfiddle with your whole css file maby we could track down the prob

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot paste the entire code . But i have checked via firebug and i 100% sure theres nothing overriding it

Comment: not much else i can do for you then im afraid, as it clearly works in the jsfiddle good luck

Comment: I just found a very old Firefox (well, Netscape) bug which suggests this is intended behaviour: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1929 - perhaps try setting the spans to inline block?

Answer (score 0):

The word "Check" is the only one that works because it is actually capitalized in your HTML.

If you can't figure out what's overriding you could add a class to your span.

`.caps { text-transform:capitalize; }`

```
<h1>
   <span class="caps">check</span> 
   <span class="caps">this</span> 
   <span class="caps"> out</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Hmm well if the you do not leave a space before the word this and out ie <span class="caps"> this</span> and then try only the word check will be capitalized.<h1><span class="caps">check</span><span class="caps">this</span><span class="caps">out</span></h1>